# Where's the functor in the natural transformation?

Tags: haskell, functor, category-theory

I've had this question on the very back of my mind ever since I saw the [definition of natural transformations](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/category-extras-0.53.5/docs/src/Control-Functor-Extras.html#%3a~%3E) in the Edward Kmett's old category-extras package:

```
-- | A natural transformation between functors f and g.
type f :~> g = forall a. f a -> g a
```

But now reading Stephen Diehl's blog post on [adjunctions](http://www.stephendiehl.com/posts/adjunctions.html), I find this:

> A natural transformation in our context will be a polymorphic function
>   associated with two Haskell functor instances f and g with type
>   signature (Functor f, Functor g) => forall a. f a -> g a. Which could
>   be written with the following type synonym.
>
> ```
> type Nat f g = forall a. f a -> g a
> ```

Which was a slap in the face of my "I'll continue ignoring this" attitude. So for the question: Why is okay to suddenly drop the functor constraints?

Comment: When you use `Nat`, you will be supplying types. The type synonym itself makes no use of the fact that they are Functors. Only when you use it does that make a difference, if that makes sense.

Comment: Hmmmm. The `forall` itself reduces the number of non-natural transform functions you can define, even if the Functors in question aren't initially evident/knocking about.

Comment: Read the excellent [You could have defined natural transformations](http://blog.sigfpe.com/2008/05/you-could-have-defined-natural.html) for a better explanation of the relationship between polymorphism and natural transformations.

Comment: I don't quite understand your first comment, even after reading the linked article. Sure, `f` and `g` have to be polymorphic - but that isn't the same as being a functor. What am I missing? And: thanks for the link; a quick read through it didn't settle my doubts, but it does seem very interesting.

Comment: @user2141650 Actually, `f` and `g` don't need to be polymorphic (if you're talking about a specific natural transformation). For example, we might talk about the natural transformation `safeHead :: Nat [] Maybe`. `a` must be polymorphic and universally quantified though, for it to be natural.

Comment: Also, by not putting the Functor constraints on the synonym we avoid putting Functor constraints where we don't need them but we can still have them where we do need them. For instance, you might have a function that maps a natural transformation over both the input and the output of some kind of process (such as another function in this example) `natPromap :: Nat f g -> (g a -> f b) -> (f a -> g b)`. In this way we only need to put a Functor constraint when we actually use `fmap`.

Comment: @DavidYoung I meant that that the functions `f` (and `g`) must be polymorphic - i.e., take any `a` - not that `Nat` must be. I think we're just using our terminology differently.

Comment: I thought of another possible reason: Not all Haskell functors can be instances of the `Functor` type class. Some `Contravariant` instances, for example

Comment: @user2141650 Sorry I didn't reply earlier. (If you had put @AndrewC, I'd have got a notification.) It's the natural transform iself that has to be a fully polymorphic function (thus the `forall`), not `f` and `g`.

Comment: @user2141650 The mathematical definition of a natural transform is a function eta_A from F(A) to G(A) for each object A of the category, such that if we take any function h:A->B, eta_B.F(h) = G(h).eta_A. The haskell equivalent of "eta_A for every object" is a polymorphic function `eta :: F a -> G a`, and the condition becomes that for **any** function `h::a->b`, `eta.fmap h = fmap h.eta`. With types, that's `(eta::F b -> G b) . ((fmap h)::F a -> F b) = ((fmap h)::G a -> G b) . (eta::F a -> G a)`. That *any* condition severely limits which functions can represent transforms, as per the article.

Answer (score 2):

It is not allowed in Haskell to put a constraint on a type synonym. And even for datatypes, it has been deprecated in Haskell 2010. Instead, the constraint should be put on the functions that operate on values of this type.

Comment: Doesn't that only apply to `data` types, not type synonyms? What about the lens type synonyms, for example?

Comment: Actually, now that I think about it, the lens types are a bit different because the Functor type variables are universally quantified. I still suspect that the deprecation you're referring to only applies to `data` types though (maybe `newtype` as well).

Comment: This works just fine for me if I enable `RankNTypes` and `TypeOperators`: `type f :-> g = forall x . (Functor f) => f x -> g x`

Comment: @Tarmil I think you have a point (as does David Young in his comments to the question, if I understand him correctly). E.g `test3 natt fn pt = natt $ fmap fn pt`, where `test3 :: (f :-> g) -> (a -> b) -> f a -> g b`, and (`:->`) is as Gabriel defined it above, doesn't typecheck because it still requires the `Functor f` constraint. So the situation with type synonyms with constraints is in fact similar to that with DatatypeContexts, except that it looks like they *haven't* been deprecated for some reason, and doesn't even require an extension!